# Integer Division in Negative Numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, arithmetic-expressions, integer-division

I'm testing big integers in Python; they are implemented as an object with sign and an array of digits. It's, basically, to describe Karatsuba Multiplication, and, for those big integers, I need the same behaviour like oridinary numbers with integer division by `10`, and, there is a problem:
Why, in Python, `-22 // 10 = -3`?

Comment: Because `//` is floor division, so rounding **down**, not towards zero.`-22 / 10` is `-2.2`, rounding down makes that `-3`.

Comment: [Why Python's Integer Division Floors](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dividing by `//` is a floor division.

Floor division goes to the lower number without a `.`

- `22 // 10` results to the next lower value `2`.
- `-22 // 10` results to the next lower value `-3`

To do a normal division you can run
    -22 / 10
This results into

```
- 2.2
```